# Recovery is not mentioned in “_cat/recovery”

Tags: elasticsearch

Yesterday I had to restart my server. After loading I checked that elastic-search is running and found that 4 of are `INITIALIZING` status and 1 is `Unalocated`.
My configuration is built with:

- Elastic v2.3
- 5 shards hosted on same server ("node-01").
- 8 CPU\30GB RAM
- less then 10GB of data.

Result of GET `/_cat/shards`:

```
index shard prirep state ip node
MyIndex 4 p INITIALIZING 127.0.0.1 node-01
MyIndex 3 p INITIALIZING 127.0.0.1 node-01
MyIndex 1 p INITIALIZING 127.0.0.1 node-01
MyIndex 2 p UNASSIGNED
MyIndex 0 p INITIALIZING 127.0.0.1 node-01
.kibana 0 p UNASSIGNED
```

As you can see, `MyIndex->Shard #2` is unassigned - so I called POST `/_cluster/reroute` (from "node-01" to "node-01").

From my previous experience, this initialize loading is takes a lot of time. So I leave the machine working and checked again after 12 hours.

After 12 hours the results of `/_cat/shards` was the same (aka 4 initializing, 1 unassigned). At this point, I was expecting to get better results.

Here it come even more strange. I called GET `/_cat/recovery` and ES respond 200 but the list is empty. That's mean that nothing is happen?

What do you recommend me to do? Why the recovery list is empty if the shards are `INITIALIZING`?
At this point, the most important thing is to be able to see the "recovery" process, if occur.

Comment: With that old version you are missing quite some good tooling unfortunately. I'd start from the logs to see what is happening there

Answer (score 0):

Use [cluster allocation explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/cluster-allocation-explain.html) to understand why your shards are not being allocated.

Comment: My elastic version is v2.3. This explain API isn't exists on this version.

Comment: How to find the reason on older versions?

Comment: Does index recovery API show any helpful info ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-recovery.html

Comment: No. Calling `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_recovery?pretty&human"` gives the result `{}` - as I understand it - no recovery process is taking place. Am I wrong?